# After changing my android icons this happened in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Launching lib/main.dart on SM G955F in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/canseyhan/Documents/Flutter/bugunneyesem/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.bugunneyesem:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
> 2

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Do you have ic_launcher in mipmap folder?

Comment: are your new icons named the same as the old ones? the error is basically saying that `1mipmap/ic_launcher` located in line 16 of your `AndroidManifest.xml` can't be found.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed all af them are in dravable-v21 folder I mean all the minimal things but I don't have a ic_launcher folder

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyadhow can solve that?

Comment: Put your new icons in mipmap folder instead of dravable-v21

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed if you are talking about the png logo files in mipmap files yes I do ic_launcher.png's

Comment: could you show the screen shot of each mipmap folder so that I can help you

Answer (score 1):

Go to `**\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml**

Then under **<application** tag, under  **android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"**
change ic_launcher to the name of your icon's image name.

Then save the file.

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with cache files. So, first we need to remove all intermediate files (cache files) by `File -> Invalidate cache / Restart` option.

Still, you are facing the issue, then you have to change the app icon or change the app icon name from,

```
<application
        android:label="Test App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2">
```